# Get the avro schema from serialized byte array

Tags: arrays, serialization, deserialization, avro

I am working on implementing avro mapping for a stream processing engine.
I am new to Avro and still learning. I want to know if the avro schema (used to define the data) can be extracted from the avro serialized byte array for deserialization purpose? If so how?
In all the examples I looked all of them require me to pass schema to GenericDatumReader constructor or set the schema after construct the reader.

Comment: I don't think this can be done. To deserialise, you have to pass the schema as well.